# return phtml file content in ajax response in magento2

Tags: magento2, ajax, phtml

I am calling an controller function via Ajax and its calling and returning correct data. But how can I return Controller function respective phtml file content instead of some data from controller function.

Here is my current code that returning data  -

```
public function execute()
{
    $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isAjax()) {
        $method = $request->getParam('method');
        if($method != '')
            $regions = $this->getRegionByCountryId($request);
            $result->setData($regions);
        } else {
            $result->setData(['error' => 'method not found']);
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Its running fine and retruning data to my ajax function.

But I want to return phtml file content instead of this data, So for that I have created an handler for this and respective phtml file.

Handler file is -  booking_index_ajax.xml with below code -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="main" htmlClass="content-page">
            <block class="Mymodule\Booking\Block\BookingList"
                   name="test.booking.filtertable"
                   template="Mymodule_Booking::content/test.phtml"
                   after="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

And created an respective test.phtml file on specified location  -

```
<?php 
echo "Hello"; 
?>
```

But my test.phtml file content is not retruning, Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

You answer worked #AMIT, But I am trying to use my execute function to get Json and phtml file both - Its returning phtml if I am not applying 'return' in Json If block, But If I am applying "return $result" statement in then returning nothing. here is mine code -

```
public function execute()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isAjax()) {
        $method = $request->getParam('method');
        if ($method === 'getRegionByCountryId') {
            $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
            $regions = $this->getRegionByCountryId($request);
            $result->setData($regions);
            //return $result;
        } elseif ($method === 'getAddressesByCountryId') {
            $resultLayout = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_LAYOUT);
            return $resultLayout; 
        } else {
            $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
            $result->setData(['error' => 'method not found']);
            return $result;
        }
    }
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do some modify at controller and layout file:

**Action file look like:**

```
namespace{YourClassNameSpace};


use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class {YourClassname} extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

............
..............

    public function execute()
    {

        $resultLayout = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_LAYOUT);
        return $resultLayout; 
    }
}
```

**Now,you have add root container at your layout file booking_index_ajax.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <container name="root">
       <block class="Mymodule\Booking\Block\BookingList"
                   name="test.booking.filtertable"
                   template="Mymodule_Booking::content/test.phtml"
                   />
    </container>
</layout>
```

Comment: But I am doing something like -  using same function to return Json data and our phtml file but its not returning Json -  here is mine function - I have updated my execute function code at the end of my question  -  Plz check

Comment: #amit Please check at the end of my question......

Comment: semms ok, accept this `//return $result;` i think you should un-comment this code

Comment: It works, error was something else....Thank you :)

Comment: How we can upload specific js file in the AJax phtml file ?

Comment: maybe can. Not sure.

Comment: I want to do same thing for backend. How can i achieve it?

Can you please help me with Action file.

Answer (score 0):

You can render phtml in your controller with following code.

```
  $this->_view->loadLayout();
  $this->_view->getLayout()
                 ->createBlock("Mymodule\Booking\Block\BookingList")
                 ->setTemplate("Mymodule_Booking::content/test.phtml")
                 ->toHtml();
```